# Compare values of 1 dict and if they equal append to new list key which is equal to another dict last item

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionaries like:
r= Number of word occurrences in Text they u Sorted them by asc firstly by values then keys
w = Number of length of the words in text Sorted by asc firstly by values then keys

```py
r = {
    'aday': 3,
    'day': 3,
    'ahaha': 1,
    'donat': 1,
    'kakaw': 1
} 

w = {
    'ahaha': 5,
    'donat': 5,
    'kakaw': 5,
    'aday': 4,
    'day': 3
}
```

I'm not good with loops, with dictionaries especially.

How can I do this: if max values of `r` are equal (`aday` and `day` equal to 3 ) I want to take key which is equal to the second dictionary `w` last item (day) so I want to take `day` in this case
`q.append(day)`.

Here is what I tried:

```
for ke,va in r.items():
    for da,ty in w.items():
        if va==ty:
          g.append(r[ke])
print(g)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first make sure the dict is sorted. if u want to get the key with highest value.
then search it in second dict

```
r={'aday': 3, 'day': 3, 'ahaha': 1, 'donat': 1, 'kakaw': 1}
w={'ahaha': 5, 'donat': 5, 'kakaw': 5, 'aday': 4, 'day': 3}

r=({k: v for k, v in reversed(sorted(r.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]))})
print("sorted r: ", r) 

h = list(r)[0]
print("key with highest value: ", h)

g=[]
if h in w:
    g.append(w[h])
print(g)
```

Test Case

```
r = {'amet': 3, 'abot': 3, 'lorem': 1, 'ipsum': 1, 'dolor': 1}
r =({k: v for k, v in reversed(sorted(r.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]))})
print(r)
```

Output:
{'abot': 3, 'amet': 3, 'dolor': 1, 'ipsum': 1, 'lorem': 1}

Comment: I already sorted them by Values then by alphabetics

Comment: then what you are doing is fine but for a simpler code check my first answer.

Comment: Your code worked but another test case wrong now :D Thank you a lot

Comment: Glad =) you can share the test case. but first try yourself. you have done a good job!

Comment: When we reversed 1 test case became wrong Because in that test if Values in 1 dict is equal we need to sort them by aplhabetic  {'amet': 3, 'abot': 3, 'lorem': 1, 'ipsum': 1, 'dolor': 1} Abot must be first so when we take h = list(r)[0] it gets Amet

Comment: code is returning {'abot': 3, 'amet': 3, 'dolor': 1, 'ipsum': 1, 'lorem': 1}

Comment: No way maybe Another case another given input before print h = list(r)[0]  i printed r dict to check   {'amet': 3, 'abot': 3, 'lorem': 1, 'ipsum': 1, 'dolor': 1}

Comment: when I run this code
r = {'amet': 3, 'abot': 3, 'lorem': 1, 'ipsum': 1, 'dolor': 1}
r =({k: v for k, v in reversed(sorted(r.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]))})
print("sorted r: ", r) 
it gives output
sorted r:  {'abot': 3, 'amet': 3, 'dolor': 1, 'ipsum': 1, 'lorem': 1}

Comment: I mean we already reversed it and now we are reversing once more 1 code to all cases so if we reverse it twice 1 case always will be wrong

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want to do. but according to your code it seems like you want to get the items in both dicts which are same by key and value.

this can be a simpler code for this:

```
r={'aday': 3, 'day': 3, 'ahaha': 1, 'donat': 1, 'kakaw': 1}
w={'ahaha': 5, 'donat': 5, 'kakaw': 5, 'aday': 4, 'day': 3}

g =[]
for key in r:
    # if both key and value are same in both dicts
    if key in w and r[key] == w[key]:
        g.append(r[key])
        g.append(w[key]) 
        
print(g)
```

Comment: When the highest values in first dict Equal (highest is aday:3 = day:3) i want to take one of those keys( aday or day ) WHICH same to LAST key in Dict 2 ( day is last key in dict 2 so "day" from dict 1 is same to last item "day" in 2 dict

Comment: i have posted another answer, check that. and why are you appending in list g. it is only 1 value of 'day'. u can use a variable instead of list.

Answer (score 1):

In the code you submitted:

- `ke` is the key in `r`, so it will take the values `aday`, `day`, `ahaha`, `donat`, `kakaw`.
- `va` is the value in `r`, it will take the values `3`, `3`, `1`, `1`, `1`.

Similarly, in the `w` dict, `da` is the key and `ty` is the value.

So to take the key of the second array, you should change the append in your code for:

```
g.append(da)
```

Comment: In my code i kinda compare Values in 2 dicts and take if values is equal but its not what i want now i think about okay another  way i will edit my question can u look at it one more time then?